# Getting the first instance in a JSON array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, json, processing

I'm sure this is a simple fix but for some reason I cant retrieve the first instance from my JSON Array. Here is the data i'm trying to parse 
https://api.gdax.com/products/btc-gbp/book

here is my code:

```
String url = "https://api.gdax.com/products/";
String btcQuery = "btc-gbp/book";
JSONObject json;

void setup() {
  size(600, 360);
  loadData();
}
void loadData(){
  // Load the JSON url
  json = loadJSONObject(url + btcQuery);

  // Grab the element we want
  JSONArray bitcoinPrice = json.getJSONArray("asks");  //.getJSONObject(0);
  //JSONObject btcPrice = bitcoinPrice.getJSONObject(0);

    println ("Bitcoin Price " + btcPrice);
  }
```

in it's current state this returns

Bitcoin Price [[
  "11098.85",
  "0.32805486",
  1
]]

However I only want the current price of bitcoin ( "11098.85") which I believe is the first instance of the "asks" array. 
Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: As you can see in the actual JSON, the array you are interested in is nested in another array. In other words, `bitcoinPrice.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject(0)` might help.

Comment: btcPrice is a an array where it has one element of type array as well. So to be able to pull the frist element of that element array, you need to again convert it into a json array and use get(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"asks" is an array but with only one element and that element is another array.

So you can try this:

```
// Grab asks array
JSONArray bitcoinPrice = json.getJSONArray("asks");
JSONArray askFirstElement = bitcoinPrice.getJSONArray(0);
System.out.println(askFirstElement.getString(0));
```